# How to change the icons of angular/pwa on Ionic 5?

Tags: angular, ionic5

I'm doing "ionic cordova resources" to change the icons by default from @angular/pwa but still remains, how to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ionic cordova resources` command is only used for native build and it won't work with Angular PWA.

For this, the config of the PWA can be found inside the `manifest.webmanifest` file. From there, you can change the name and the icons of your PWA. Or you can do it by changing the icons right away inside this folder: `src/assets/icons` with the right resolution and names for each icon.

Please note that you can also change the favicon from `src/assets/icon` and replace it.

You can check [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xm_EZAGGGdU) for more information.

Comment: It's not well explained, its different manifest than the genuine one... change it please

Comment: Can you add more info about the manifest you have, structure ...etc?

Comment: I meant is not the AndroidManifest... is other system, PWA too different from the other system

Comment: I was actually talking about the `manifest.webmanifest`. I edited the answer and added more info